# Quais são as boas praticas do MVC com Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, mvc

Gostaria de saber quais são as boas praticas do MVC utilizando o Entity Framework, a respeito sobre as pastas do MVC.

Quando eu crio o Entity Framework, ele me cria automaticamente o arquivo do banco, e o arquivo de Context.

Em qual pasta seria ideal (boas praticas), criar o Entity Framework?

Na pasta MODEL, ou eu posso criar uma pasta chamada Context fora da pasta MODEL?

Pois dentro do Entity Framework criado contém as classes do banco seria dentro do model, não é ?

Comment: O Ideal seria você criar sua aplicação em DDD. só isso.

Comment: `Em qual pasta seria ideal (boas praticas), criar o Entity Framework? ` Como assim, criar o que? Esta frase não faz sentido. `Na pasta MODEL, ou eu posso criar uma pasta chamada Context fora da pasta MODEL?` Pode, a questão é saber se deve, e isso depende do que quer fazer, o que não tem na pergunta. `Pois dentro do Entity Framework criado contém as classes do banco seria dentro do model, não é ?` Provavelmente. A pergunta não está muito clara. Por isso as respostas atuais acabam não fazendo muito sentido também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria uma boa prática separar o modelo de dados do modelo de exibição.
Para isso, crie um projeto só com a parte de banco, qualquer modelo/pattern conhecido (DAC, Repository, etc) e coloque as models lá.

No projeto `MVC` coloque as models que vai usar nas views, nem que sejam iguais às models no `EntityFramework`. Por quê?

Imagina que você tem uma model para entrada de dados em um form, e quer adicionar à essa model validações, `DataAnnotations` por exemplo. Você pode pode fazer isso livremente nessa model sem ter de alterar a model do `EntityFramework`.

Se por exemplo você tiver um campo no banco para documentos, CPF, CNPJ, RG, etc que são tipos numéricos. Na view você quer usar uma máscara para por pontos, tracos, barras, etc, e quer usar um atributo string, como ia fazer? Separando as models isso não seria problema.

Aqui só algumas situações onde é recomendado separa o modelo de dados do modelo de exibição, por isso sugiro deixar na pasta Models do MVC as models que servem exclusivamente às Views, e os modelos de dados do banco em outro projeto.

Um exemplo seria:

```
ProjetoDados
   Models
       ... aqui vão as models do EntityFramework

ProjetoMVC
   Controllers
   Views
   Models
       ... aqui vão as models para atender as Views
```

Answer (score 0):

Sim eu colocaria na Models.

Ou então numa biblioteca de classes caso fosse comum a mais de um projecto

Answer (score 0):

Subdiretórios são sempre uma forma elegante de organizar seu codigo.

Como se trada de dados, é importante que fiquem dentro do Model, obedecendo a arquitetura MVC. No exemplo, faço a distinção de arquivos que são Entity e ADO. Dentro de uma área (módulo) que chamo de Qualidade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]